# Extend an array of hash with values from an array

Tags: ruby

I have this array

```
types = ['first', 'second', 'third']
```

and this array of hashes

```
data = [{query: "A"}, {query: "B"}, {query:"C", type: 'first'}]
```

Now I have to "extend" each Hash of *data* with each type if not already exists. All existing keys of the hash must be copied too (eg. :query).
So the final result must be:

```
results = [
  {query: "A", type: 'first'}, {query: "A", type: "second"}, {query: "A", type: "third"},
  {query: "B", type: 'first'}, {query: "B", type: "second"}, {query: "D", type: "third"},
  {query: "C", type: 'first'}, {query: "C", type: "second"}, {query: "C", type: "third"}
]
```

the data array is quite big for performance matters.

Comment: What about that `type: 'first'` from the `data` array's last element?

Comment: Sometimes the :type could be already present and it must not to be included again

Comment: "must not be included again" - Yet it is overwritten anyway?

Comment: Yes, it could be overwritten if is faster

Comment: What's up with `query: "D"`, where did that come from?

Comment: _"if not already exists"_ sounds as if you want to preserve the original value. In your results however, it seems to be gone.

Comment: In results query C still has the hash with type=first

Comment: "still has the hash with type=first" - and also type=second and type=third.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Array#product`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#product-method) to combine both arrays and [`Hash#merge`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Hash.html#merge-method) to add the `:type` key:

```
data.product(types).map { |h, t| h.merge(type: t) }
#=> [
#     {:query=>"A", :type=>"first"}, {:query=>"A", :type=>"second"}, {:query=>"A", :type=>"third"},
#     {:query=>"B", :type=>"first"}, {:query=>"B", :type=>"second"}, {:query=>"B", :type=>"third"},
#     {:query=>"C", :type=>"first"}, {:query=>"C", :type=>"second"}, {:query=>"C", :type=>"third"}
#   ]
```

Note that the above will replace existing values for `:type` with the values from the `types` array. (there can only be one `:type` per hash)

If you need more complex logic, you can pass a block to `merge` which handles existing / conflicting keys, e.g.:

```
h = { query: 'C', type: 'first' }
t = 'third'

h.merge(type: t) { |h, v1, v2| v1 }         # preserve existing value
#=> {:query=>"C", :type=>"first"}

h.merge(type: t) { |h, v1, v2| [v1, v2] }   # put both values in an array
#=> {:query=>"C", :type=>["first", "third"]}
```

Answer (score 3):

We see that each hash in `data` is mapped to an array of three hashes and the resulting array of three arrays is then to be flattended, suggesting we skip a step by using the method [Enumerable#flat_map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map) on `data`. The construct is as follows.

```
n = types.size
  #=> 3
data.flat_map { |h| n.times.map { |i| ... } }
```

where `...` produces a hash such as

```
{:query=>"A", :type=>"second"}
```

Next we see that the value of `:type` in the array of hashes returned equals `:first` then `:second` then `:third` then `:first` and so on. That is, the value cycles among the elements of `types`. Also, the fact that one of the hashes in `data` has a key `:type` is irrelevant, as it will be overwritten. Therefore, for each value of `i` (`0`, `1` or `2`) in `map`'s block above, we wish to merge `h` with `{ type: types[i%n] }`:

```
n = types.size  
data.flat_map { |h| n.times.map { |i| h.merge(type: types[i%n]) } }
  #=> [{:query=>"A", :type=>"first"}, {:query=>"A", :type=>"second"},
  #    {:query=>"A", :type=>"third"},
  #    {:query=>"B", :type=>"first"}, {:query=>"B", :type=>"second"},
  #    {:query=>"B", :type=>"third"},
  #    {:query=>"C", :type=>"first"}, {:query=>"C", :type=>"second"},
  #    {:query=>"C", :type=>"third"}]
```

---

We may alternatively make use of the method [Array#cycle](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-cycle).

```
enum = types.cycle
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["first", "second", "third"]:cycle>
```

As the name of the method suggests,

```
enum.next
  #=> "first"
enum.next
  #=> "second"
enum.next
  #=> "third"
enum.next
  #=> "first"
enum.next
  #=> "second"
...
```

*ad infinitum*. Before continuing let me reset the enumerator.

```
enum.rewind
```

See [Enumerator#next](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-rewind) and [Enumerator#rewind](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-rewind).

```
n = types.size  
data.flat_map { |h| n.times.map { h.merge(type: enum.next) } }
  #=> <as above>
```